# How to use an if conditional in a WireMock JSON stub?

Tags: json, handlebars.js, wiremock-standalone

I need to use if conditional in my stub. I know there are the different scenarios you can create with body patterns but this does not work in my case because I am getting a variable number of objects in the payload and I need to use a for loop to check every one of them.
So my request payload would look similar to this:

```
[
   { "todo_id": 1 },
   { "todo_id": null },
   { "todo_id": 3 }
]
```

I want to respond with the `todo_id` where there was one and respond with a random integer where there is `null`, so my response payload so far is this:

```
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "[ {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$') as |todo|}}
                  { \"todo_id\":
                      {{#if (todo.todo_id == null) }}
                          1{{randomValue length=1 type='NUMERIC'}}
                      {{else}}
                          {{todo.todo_id}}
                      {{/if}}
                },
            {{/each}} ]"
}
```

I know you can't body spaced out like that but I did it to make it easer to read the code.

So the for each loop definitely works, I've tried it without if statement and it works fine. But I cannot get the if statement working for me.

Any ideas on how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I got an answer for this on Google Group for WireMock.

Apparently to compare values you're supposed to use `eq` operator.

So changing my conditional part of the code to look like this

```
{{#eq todo.todo_id null}}
    1{{randomValue length=1 type='NUMERIC'}}
{{else}}
    {{todo.todo_id}}
{{/eq}}
```

solved the problem.